# choose language first before installation android app xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, multilingual

I'm using Xamarin C# to develop android app, and i want to let user choose the language first before installing the app on their device.

I only can do it after installing the app but before i don't have any idea

Comment: This sort of thing is not possible, as you cannot give multiple versions of the same app. Even if you were hosting it manually, it's unlikely you'd generate a build on the fly

Answer (score 2):

**It is simply not possible**

ideal way is to check the device default language at first time user opens the app and proceed accordingly.

you can create [Language-Specific Resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/localization/#Language-Specific_Resources) which will allow android OS to use the appropriate language resources as the device default language  or later you can also use them [via coding at run time](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/localization/#Using_Resources_in_Code)